# Why can't I see my entity classes in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: entity-framework-4

I am following an example in a book concerning creating entity classes from an existing database (I personally prefer Code First, but I have no choice the example is Database First!)

I when I generate the classes using the designer, I get four files under the Northwind.edmx - Northwind.Content.tt, Northwind.Designer.cs, Northwind.edmx.diagram and Northwind.tt

I would expect to see Northwind.Context.cs and Product.cs (in my case). These do not show up in Solution Explorer. I have looked in Explorer and the files are there!, so I tried to drag them into the solution but they still don't appear. I have tried Add Existing Item too and they are not there. I have clicked Show All Files and they're not there.

What am I missing? Please help!

Mark

Comment: Did you expand the tt file in the solution explorer? (The little triangle at the left of the name).